# access property of an instance property of class that inherits from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why am I not able to assign value to the `myBrowser` variable if in a hybrid app (MVC + webforms, but predominantly webforms), I add in a class `Class1` this inner class

```
public class MyMvcController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{

}
```

and then in a method belonging to Class1 I try to reference it as follows
`HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase myBrowser = new MyMvcController().Request.Browser;`
at which point myBrowser is null.
PS: Request property is an instance property of Controller
Syntactically what I've done is correct (no errors)

I'm including the concrete example below:

```
public class Class1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
        public class MyMvcController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
        {

        }

        public string getBrowser()
        {
            return new MyMvcController().Request.Browser;
            //HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase browser = new MyMvcController().Request.Browser;
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            string b = getBrowser();
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) Provide a *complete* example. 2) Care to format your question. 3) Don't think a manual instantiation of an MVC `Controller` will lead to a fully initialized instance.

Comment: MVC does work to get your `Controller` up and running with the current context.  You can't just expect that information to be available out of thin air.  Imagine instantiating a `Controller` this way in a console application.  What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Thank you both. I would need MyMvcController  to work as the Controller it inherits from e.g. if it doesn't override a method/property etc with its own implementation, the implementation from the parent class (Mvc.Controller) will take effect (this should apply for initialization, right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` is abstract, so you won't be able to create an instance of it.

Within your MyMvcController  you can probably just do `HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = this.Request.Browser;`

If you create a new instance of MyMvcController() i'd be surprised if the request property was populated.